# Android Copy a zip to /data/local

Tags: android, copy, inputstream, boot

Hi I'm working on a simple boot animation app but i'm guessing this is a permissions problem but i'm not really sure as i'm new to this but anyway here is my code. I'm trying to copy a boot animation from the sdcard to /data/local and rename it to bootanimation.zip I know the code is fine because if i copy to another folder on the sdcard say /mnt/sdcard/folder/bootanimation.zip it works and the file is renamed but i can't copy to /data/local my phone is rooted and all but i guess my app needs to ask for su or my manifest needs more permissions. Any solutions as to why i can't copy to /data/local would be a huge help. Thank you for any help

```
try {
    FileChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/boots/1bootanimation.zip").getChannel();
    FileChannel dstChannel = new FileOutputStream("/data/local/bootanimation.zip").getChannel();
    dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());
    srcChannel.close();
    dstChannel.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
```

Comment: you'd have to remount /data/ as rw (read-write) as by default its ro (read only).  normally this would be possible, but since your phone is rooted its doable.

Comment: ha i feel stupid :) didn't think i was going to need su for me to write to data but that makes sense ha love the small things

Comment: Would it be the same as like in bash (was a scripter before i got to my first app) that is 

mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /data

Comment: yeah i think `exec("su");` then `exec("mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /data");` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem actually wasn't mounting data, as that mounts automatically like i thought problem was the permissions on the /data/local my app didn't have permission to write to the folder once i chmod the folder it works perfectly